# How can I move an 8-bit address into a 16-bit register in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

Here, I'm trying to move the variable X (which is an 8-bit variable) into the register bx (which is a 16-bit register). How can I move the value of X into the register bx in this case?

```
.686p
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 2048

.data
X byte 5
ExitProcess proto, exitcode:dword
.code

start:
invoke  ExitProcess, 0

mov bx, X; 1>p4.asm(13): error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size

end start ;what does the end statement do?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot move 8 bit address to 16 bit register](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959446/cannot-move-8-bit-address-to-16-bit-register)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to Rahul's answer, if you also need to zero out `bh` and are working on anything 80386 or newer (as indicated by the `.686p`) is:

```
movzx bx, X
```

Of if you are using X as a signed value and needs to sign-extend `bx`:

```
movsx bx, X
```

Comment: The directive `.686p` satisfies the requirements.

Comment: I suspected that, but wanted to guard against anyone treating the directive as boilerplate. (To be fair, I probably haven't written 16-bit code in 20 years, so the assumption seems pretty safe anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

The low 8-bits of BX are addressable as BL.

So, all you need to do is:
`mov bl, X`

Comment: Wow, that was quick - I didn't expect to see an answer so soon. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer (the check thingy) if this helped you :)