# Cannot move 8 bit address to 16 bit register

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, emu8086

I am trying to assign variable to register here is the code:

```
       ORG 100h

        var1 DB 10  ;
        var2 DB 20  ;

        MOV BX,var1 ; error : operands do not match: 16 bit register and 8 bit address
RET
END
```

But if swap the 4th line with:

```
MOV BL, var1;
```

it works. So my question is **why can’t** I move **8 bit variable** into **much larger 16 bit register**?

I have already referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274265/error-operands-do-not-match-16-bit-and-8-bit-register-in-assembly-language), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066039/assembly-emu8086-not-allowing-moving-of-bytes-into-8-bit-registers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540450/how-can-i-move-an-8-bit-address-into-a-16-bit-register-in-x86-assembly) OP but it does not answer my question.

**NOTE:**

1. I am using emu8086 assembler
2. I am new to assembly language so I apologise if it's a stupid question.

Comment: You need to use `movzx` or `movsx` if available to move with zero or sign extension respectively. It might not be available in 8086, in which case you need to move into `BL` as you have done and zero `BH` yourself. As to why: because they created the architecture this way :)

Comment: @Jester:  It's not, only cbw.  I updated the http://stackoverflow.com/tags/8086/info tag wiki with a link to wikipedia with a table of when various instructions were introduced.  Also with a diatribe about how learning asm on 16bit 8086 is dumb.  But anyway, ome of the major insns 8086 is missing are movzx/sx, and `bt*` bit-manip.

Comment: upvoting only because that error message is badly worded and misleading.

Comment: BTW, this actually *is* a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540450/how-can-i-move-an-8-bit-address-into-a-16-bit-register-in-x86-assembly, which you linked.  The answers there don't try to explain why it's an error, and movzx doesn't work on 8086, but still.  Voted to close that as a duplicate of this, since this one has more detailed answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> why can’t I move 8 bit variable into much larger 16 bit register?

Becase the machine code `MOV` instruction needs both the source operand and destination operand to be the same size. This is needed because a `MOV` instruction by itself doesn't specify how to fill the remaining bits of the larger destination register.

To allow for different size move operations, Intel added `MOVZX` and `MOVSX` in the 80386 CPU, which allow a smaller source operand (the destination is always a 32 bit register). -SX and -ZX suffixes denotes what the previously unused bits of the destination register should be filled with.

On 16-bit Intel processors, there is the instruction `CBW` (Convert Byte to Word), which does a sign extend from 8 to 16 bits. Unfortunately, this only works for the accumulator (register AL/AX), so you'd have to do something like:

```
mov al,var1
cbw
mov bx,ax
```

`cbw` does a sign extension. If your `var1` is unsigned, you can do simply as this:

```
mov bl,var1
xor bh,bh  ; equivalent to mov bh,0 but faster and only one byte opcode
```

Or, as Peter Cordes states:

```
xor bx,bx    ;clear the whole destination register
mov bl,var1  ;update the least significant byte of the register with the 8-bit value
```

Comment: `xor bx,bx  /  mov bl, var1` would be better, because it's more like one of the good idioms you'd want to use in 32 or 64bit mode (of zeroing the full register before using a smaller part).  It breaks the false dependency on the old contents of the full register, but zeroing the upper and lower halves separately won't.  Also, `movs/zx r16, r/m8` is valid.  It's also valid with a 64bit dest reg, but that's discouraged for `movzx` because it's identical to movzx with a 32bit dest.  There's a new opcode for `movsx r64, r/m32`, but not for movzx.

Comment: Also, `mov bh,bh` is a 2-byte instruction, same code-size as `mov bh, 0`.  If you are going to write BH, mov is actually better for 8-bit registers on modern CPUs.   [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45660139).  (But both ways are bad vs. xor-zeroing the whole 16-bit register, like my previous comment.)

Answer (score 1):

You're using an assembler that keeps track of how you declare symbols to figure out what operand size to use.

`var1` isn't an 8 bit address, it's a 16bit address (not counting the segment) that points at the first of two 8-bit variables.  So the assembler error message is badly worded and confusing.

NASM would do what you said, and do a 16bit load.  You'd find `var1` in `bl` and `var2` in `bh`.  Presumably you could write `mov bx, word [var1]`, or `word ptr` or whatever, to get your assembler to emit the 16bit load.

(Actually, NASM would assemble `mov  BX, var1`  into a `mov r16, imm16`, putting the address into the register.  Always use `[]` around memory references, for consistency, because that works in NASM and MASM variants of Intel syntax.  NASM doesn't support the `mov BX, offset var1` syntax for writing the mov-immediate form, though.)