# assembly moving al register value into ax

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I am completely new to the assembly and I have some question about registers still after searching through. 
currently I'm trying to divide a value over and over again by doing:

1.divide ax over bl (seems that remainder goes to ah, quotient goes to al)

2.move al(quotient) to ax

3.jump to 5 if ax is less or equal to 0

4.jump to 1

5.end

The problem occurs on instruction 2, as i'm trying to move 8 bit value into 16 bit value.
Anybody have idea on how to solve the problem?

I am using emu8086 so the register has only x, h and l.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33959900/2970947

Comment: As you mention in step 3 "ax is less or equal to 0", maybe you did want to use signed integers everywhere? Then you have to use `idiv` for division, and [`cbw`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CBW:CWDE:CDQE.html) is simplest 8086 way to sign-extend `al` into `ax`, this is old 8086 instruction, available in emu8086 - while `movzx/movsx` are 80386 instructions, so when writing modern x86 asm code, you would rather want to use `movsx [e/r]ax,al` just for consistency with other extensions (when target register is different than `ax`). When unsigned, answers cover that (`and ax,0FFh` is ok).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question basically boils down to:

> How do I move `al` to `ax`.

And the answer to that is that you *don't* move it, it's already there. The 16-bit `ax` register is made of of the two 8-bit registers `ah` and `al`:

```
  ______________ ax ______________
 /                                \
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|f|e|d|c|b|a|9|8|  |7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0| <- individual bits
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 \____    _____/    \_____    ____/
       ah                  al
```

If you want to ensure that the *entirety* of `ax` is set to whatever was in `al`, you just need to clear the `ah` part, with something like:

```
and ax, 0ffh
```

This will clear all but the lowest (rightmost) eight bits, effectively setting the `f..8` region to all zeros, and therefore ensuring that `ax` becomes `al`.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I thought the register had three different parts ax, ah and al! The problem solved too :)

Comment: On a modern CPU, use `movzx eax, al` for good performance.  (or preferably, `movzx ecx, al` or [any register other than the one that contains the source byte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44193770/224132)).  For small code-size, or 8086, use `mov ah, 0` to do the same thing as `and ax, 0xff`, but with only 2 bytes of code instead of 4.  ([xor-zeroing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and) doesn't save any size for byte registers, and only has major advantages for dword registers.)

Comment: Oh, actually `and` is a good suggestion here, because it sets flags based on the quotient, and you want to branch on that anyway.  (i.e. `and ax, 0FFh` / `jz and_result_was_zero`)

Answer (score 2):

You have to distinguish between two cases:

**Case 1:**

`al` contains an unsigned number (0...255). In this case you have to clear the upper 8 bits of the 16-bit register `ax`.

As "paxdiablo" wrote in his answer you could use `and ax, 0FFh` (3 bytes) for this job however the instruction `mov ah, 0` (2 bytes) should be more efficient. Both instructions would do the same.

**Case 2:**

`al` contains a signed number (-128...127). In this case you have to clear the upper 8 bits of `ax` if the highest bit of `al` is clear; otherwise you have to set them.

The `cbw` instruction (this instruction has no arguments because it will only work with the `ax` register) will do that job.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can move a smaller value into a larger location using [movsx](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSX:MOVSXD.html) or [movzx](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVZX.html). `Movsx` [maintains the sign of the value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) (so that if you move 0xfe, that becomes 0xfffe) whereas `movzx` zero-extends the value (so that 0xfe becomes 0x00fe).

However, in your specific case, you don't need to do any moving at all. `AL` already designates the lower 8 bits of `AX`. All you need to do is clear the high bits of AX, which you can do in a variety of ways, but `and ax, 0xff` is probably the simplest.

Comment: he mentioned he is using EMU8086. it is more or less an 80186 emulator. `movsx` and `movzx` aren't available.